# How can I restart a IIS site by using appcmd commands?

Tags: iis

I'm wondering the possibility of restart a site in the IIS 7.5 via appcmd commands. To list the all sites available I got success by using:

**appcmd.exe list site**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a couple of options here:

To restart an individual app pool, try [(Reference)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc770764%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

```
appcmd recycle apppool /apppool.name:string
```

OR

```
 appcmd stop apppool /apppool.name:Marketing 
 appcmd start apppool /apppool.name:Marketing
```

To restart an individual website, try [(Reference)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc772137%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

```
 appcmd stop site /site.name:contoso 
 appcmd start site /site.name:contoso
```

or you could restart the whole IIS server:

```
iisreset
```

I think this works on IIS 7.5  It definitely does on 7.0 and I've been informed by a colleague that it does on 8, so no reason to believe 7.5 won't

Hope this helps

Comment: by using your penultimate option, I got an error when tryed to run this line replacing the "contoso" string with "my_real_site_name.com" where says: _The attribute "site.name" is not supported in the current command usage_. Am I using the command in a wrong way?

Comment: Fazer 87, as you can see below, I found my answer based on your above, therefore, I'll mark as the accepted answer! I also would like to give you a up vote due the useful extra commands, however, I haven't points enough to do that. Sorry =/

Comment: Thanks for the accolade :)  As long as you're sorted and workng :)

Comment: The solution works, but there shoudn't be any spaces between "/site.name: contoso" for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I was able to get it working on IIS 7.5 by changing the following details in the @Fazer87's command:

Instead:

```
appcmd start site /site.name: contoso
```

Change to:

```
appcmd start site "my_real_site_name.com" (also note the double quotes)
```